# Is there a way to add tools to the Desire2Learn WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: desire2learn

In Desire2Learn, when you click the Insert Stuff button in the WYSIWYG editor, you can add things like YouTube videos and Flickr into page content. There seem to be several third party tools listed there. We have our own video tool, among other items, that we would like to add to the list. Is there an api to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

With version 10.4 of the Desire2Learn Suite, you can add items to the Insert Stuff Framework using the Remote Plugin Service. Your tool needs to be configured to use Learning Tools Interoperability (LTI) to connect to the Desire2Learn Learning Suite, and can use Valence Learning Framework APIs to extend beyond the capabilities of LTI. Details of the Remote Plugin Service are available in the following documentation topic: http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/ui-ext/rplugins.html